# My code is not working - Form is not getting submitted

Tags: django, ajax, forms, post

```
<!-- The form markup -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            <div>
                <h1 class="text-primary fw-bold text-center log-in-title">Log In</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="mt-3 text-center">
                <!-- The form -->
                <form class="mod-auth">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input id="mod-auth-username" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input id="mod-auth-password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                     </div>
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 mx-auto">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Log in</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <hr>
                <h6>Don't have an account? <a href="/sign-up/?next={{request.path}}">Sign up</a></h6>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
// AJAX Post request
$(document).on('submit', '.mod-auth', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('hi');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/log-in/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            username: $('#mod-auth-username').val(),
            password: $('#mod-auth-password').val(),
        },
        success: function() {},
    });
});
```

```
# views.py
# This method already handles a log in page and the AJAX post request code given above sends request here.
def log_in(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            if request.POST.get('next', ''):
                return redirect(f"{request.POST.get('next', '')}")
            return redirect(f"/{username}/")
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Either the username or password is wrong! Note that your password and username are case sensitive')
            return redirect(f'{request.path}?next={request.POST.get("next", "")}')

    return render(request, 'log_in.html')
```

My code is not working, I have added a jQuery form submit event, which is not working.
I am unable to figure out what is the problem.

The form is a part of a Modal (Bootstrap), which is fired when a user tries to click a Like button without logging in, the modal contains a form, which has to be filled and submitted, then an AJAX Post request gets executed and the data is sent to the views.py.

Thank you. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro, Button type should be `submit`.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Log in</button>
```

Comment: Oh I am really sorry for that, I didn't check that. I was looking for the mistakes but I did not see the button!